Аудио не перематывается
у меня есть django приложение для аудио, но я столкнулся с проблемой, проблема в том, что музыка на сайте перематывается только тогда, когда файл загрузился полностью, а это значит, что нужно воспроизводить его почти до конца, в частности если файл длинный, кто нибудь знает как можно сделать перемотку аудио без полной подгрузки

тег выглядит так: 
